# How to make it so each time you press the enter key, a new text pops up in Java?

Tags: java, keyboard, key, java.util.scanner

Here is the code I have so far, the first time I click the enter key, "Read enter key" appears. The second time I click the enter key, both "Read enter key" and "the second hit" appear. How do I go about making it so only "second hit" appears after the second time I press the enter key?

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class love {
    static public void main (String[] args) {
        // creation the scanner to look for when the enter key is pressed 
        try (Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in)) {
            String readString = scanner.nextLine();
            while(readString!=null) {
            System.out.println(readString);

            if (readString.isEmpty()) {
                // enter the first text
                System.out.println("Read Enter Key");

            }

            if (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
                readString = scanner.nextLine();
                // enter the second text
                System.out.println("second hit");
            } else {
                readString = null;
            }
        }

    }

}

}
```

Comment: Try counting number of times you showed "hit" messages?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
**Make the following changes in your code.Hope so it works as you wanted.**

    import java.util.Scanner;
    class Love 
    {
      public static void main (String[] args) 
      {
     // creation the scanner to look for when the enter key is pressed 


          Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
          String readString = scanner.nextLine();
         while(readString!=null)
         {
                    System.out.println(readString);

                  if (readString.isEmpty()) 
                  {

                     System.out.println("Read Enter Key");
                  }

                 if (scanner.hasNextLine()) 
                 {
                      readString = scanner.nextLine();
                      System.out.println("second hit");
                      readString=null;
                 } 


          }

     }

 }
```